# Development Environment for Custom Reports?

Tags: developer

I'm looking at getting a development environment set up so I can more easily create and test custom reports and templates.  Are there any guides on doing this?  Would I be better off just setting up a complete wordpress/civi dev evnrionment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For developer documentation, see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/

To create a development environment, use [buildkit](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/)

For custom reports, you might want to check existing [report extensions](https://civicrm.org/extensions?title=&body_value=&field_extension_civi_use_target_id=96&status=All&field_extension_ready_value=All) before developing your own.

If you want to develop reports, see the [CiviReport Reference](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/civireport/) but I suggest you investigate [SearchKit](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/searchkit/overview/) ([examples](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/searchkit)) in preference to developing old-style reports.